# How to access external database table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, privileges, host, sql-grant

I have two MySQL databases in 2 different hosts.

I would like to from MySQL A table 1 to connect and retrieve data from MySQL B table 2.

I do not know which one should set up privilege in order to connecting both each other.

I keep receiving:

SELECT command denied to user 'MySQL A'@'localhost' for table 'MySQL B table 2'

Comment: what do you want to do in table 1 with the data from table 2?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up federated tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

The alternative is 2 connections, 2 queries and combine the results.